# Common Lisp type vs. class distinctions

Tags: class, types, common-lisp

In the post at [Common Lisp class hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514204/common-lisp-class-hierarchy), Rainer Joswig & Joshua Taylor carefully distinguish some of the differences between built-in Common Lisp *types* and *classes*, where classes form part of the CLOS extension to the baseline. The type/class (plus mop) distinctions are also reflected in Pfeil's comprehensive [hierarchy diagram](http://sellout.github.io/media/CL-type-hierarchy.png). Using the diagram, it seems possible to extract the two distinct hierarchies. In particular, I am currently most interested in the tops of the hierarchies; namely, the direct subtypes and subclasses of `t` (since `t` is both a type and a class). Here are some provisional subtypes/subclasses distilled from the diagram:

For the type hierarchy, the direct subtypes of `t` seem to be `atom`, `character`, `random-state`, `hash-table`, `restart`, `readtable`, `package`, `pathname`, `stream`, `function`, `array`, `sequence`, `number`, and `condition`. All other types like `float` or `list` are subtypes of one of these types. The type hierarchy is also not strictly hierarchical (since `(subtype t t) => T`, but this seems to be the only exception). (ps: the types `symbol` and `structure-object` are not included in the diagram, but also may be direct subtypes of `t`.)

For the class hierarchy, the direct subclasses of `t` include corresponding classes for all the types above (except `atom`, and perhaps `structure-object` which is now a subclass of `standard-object`(?)), plus `standard-object`.

The MOP extends CLOS by adding the class `metaobject` (plus some meta-subclasses), but does not seem to add to the direct subclasses of `t`.

Can someone verify if this understanding is correct, or provide additional clarifications?

*Note: I've discovered at least one mistake in the type hierarchy description above. All of the listed subtypes (`character`, etc.) are apparently subtypes of `atom`, so they are not direct subtypes of `t`. The only other direct subtype of `t` seems to be `sequence`, since a sequence can be a `cons` (non-atom). Moreover, `symbol` is, in fact, included in the diagram, and is also a subtype of `atom`.*

Comment: what is a 'direct subtype'? Common Lisp does not define such a concept. How is `character` a `direct subtype` of `T`, when it is a subtype of `atom`? Also the Common Lisp standard does not define all superclasses (and thus supertypes) for classes like `restart`. It might be just `T` or add something like  `structure-object` or `standard-object`. So conforming implementations might have different class hierarchies. Why speculate? Take the implementations you use and check them out. Most have enough introspective capabilities that you can get type/class information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Graphing CL Subtypes of T in LispWorks**:

Finding the subtypes:

```
(defun find-synonym-types (type1 types)
  (remove-if-not (lambda (type2)
                   (and (not (eq type1 type2))
                        (subtypep type1 type2)
                        (subtypep type2 type1)))
                 types))

(defun find-all-types-in-packages (packages &key include-nil)
  (let ((types nil))
    (loop for package in packages
          when (find-package package)
          do (do-external-symbols (sym (find-package package))
               (when (ignore-errors (subtypep sym t))
                 (let ((synonyms (find-synonym-types sym types)))
                   (if synonyms
                       (pushnew sym (get (first synonyms) :type-synonyms))
                     (pushnew sym types))))))
    (if include-nil types (remove nil types))))

(defun direct-subtypes (supertype &key all-types)
  (loop with subtypes = (remove supertype (loop for type in all-types
                                                when (subtypep type supertype)
                                                collect type))

        for type in subtypes
        when (loop for type2 in (remove type subtypes)
                   never (subtypep type type2))
        collect type))
```

Graphing it:

```
#+capi
(defun class-color (class-name)
  (typecase (find-class class-name)
    (standard-class  :blue)
    (built-in-class  :violet)
    (structure-class :brown)
    (otherwise       :red)))

#+capi
(defun graph-subtypes-from-t ()
  (let ((all-types (find-all-types-in-packages '("CL" "CLOS"))))
    (capi:contain
     (make-instance
      'capi:graph-pane
      :roots '(t)
      :children-function (lambda (type)
                           (direct-subtypes type :all-types all-types))
      :node-pane-function #'(lambda (graph-pane node)
                              (declare (ignore graph-pane))
                              (make-instance
                               'capi:item-pinboard-object
                               :text (format
                                      nil "~{~a~^, ~}"
                                      (cons node
                                            (get node :type-synonyms)))
                               :graphics-args `(:foreground
                                                ,(if (find-class node
                                                                 nil)
                                                     (class-color node)
                                                   :black))))
      :edge-pane-function #'(lambda (self from to)
                              (declare (ignore self from to))
                              (make-instance
                               'capi:arrow-pinboard-object
                               :graphics-args '(:foreground
                                                :grey))))
     :title "Common Lisp Subtypes in LispWorks")))
```

**Graph**

The types with corresponding CLOS classes are written in blue and structure classes are brown. The type `NIL` is not drawn. Included are types/classes from the CLOS MOP. Some types have more than one name. Also note that this graph is specific to LispWorks, especially what types are actually also structures, CLOS classes, built-in class or something else.

[image: Named types in Common Lisp, using LispWorks]

Comment: Note that this only comprises those types which are named by a single symbol.

Comment: @Svante: Those are *atomic type specifiers*. It makes only sense to talk about symbols as names. Something like `(integer 0 10)` would probably not be a type name, but a *compound type specifier*. `DEFTYPE` for example needs a symbol for a name. Common Lisp may allow one to define other types, but in the standard only named types are explicitly listed.

Comment: It's interesting (to me at least) that the entire type hierarchy, while allowing multiple supertypes, avoids recursion among the primitive types, except for (as far as I can tell) each type with itself (i.e., `(subtypep <type1> <type1>)` => T). Since all classes are also types, does this also hold when clos is added?

Comment: @RainerJoswig, excellent answer with a very nice and useful graph!

Comment: @RainerJoswig. I'm laminating.

Comment: `(ignore-errors (subtypep 'foo t))` returns `T` from me on SBCL 1.3.18 even when there is no type named foo. I've had better results with this variant of the hack `(ignore-errors (nth-value 1 (subtypep 'foo nil)))` (I'm assuming most impls will be certain any type isnt a subtype of the null type)

Comment: @davypough types in Common Lisp correspond to sets of values. Arrows in the above graph correspond to “is a proper subset of.” Thus a cycle in the graph (which I think is what you mean by recursion) would correspond to a set which is a proper subset of itself, ie a set which does not equal itself. If there were cycles in the graph that would be an error. Note that there is a different type of “recursion” which is not allowed: `(deftype intlist () '(or null (cons fixnum intlist)))` for a list of integers (although such a type may be represented using `satisfies`)

Answer (score 4):

The term **direct subtype** almost never makes sense.

Why do you think that `character` is a *direct subtype* of `t`?

But `character` is a subtype of `atom` which is a subtype of `t`!

Well, maybe `character` is a *direct* subtype of `atom`?

Nope, `character` is a subtype of `(or character number)` which is a subtype of `atom`.

So, maybe `character` is a *direct* subtype of `(or character number)`?

Nope, `character` is a subtype of `(or character integer)` which is a subtype of `(or character number)`.

You can think of *classes* as integers and *types* as rationals - there are no integers between 3 and 4, but there are plenty of rationals between any two different rationals.

Comment: I was referring only to primitive built-in types in the ansi standard, but it's good to remember too, as you point out, that the number of available types is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You already know that there are types and there are classes in Common Lisp.

Types categorize objects, while classes tag objects.  Moreover, an object may be of many types, but it's a direct instance of a single class.

If you ask an object for its type through `type-of`, you may get many valid answers.  A non-exhaustive example:

```
 (type-of 1)
=> (integer 1 1)
OR => bit
OR => (unsigned-byte 1)
OR => (mod 2)
OR => (integer (0) (2))
OR => (signed-byte 1)
OR => (signed-byte 16)
OR => fixnum
OR => integer
OR => (integer * *)
OR => rational
OR => real
OR => number
OR => t
OR => atom
```

For `typep` and `subtypep`, things are a lot more confusing, as you can generate types at will, like `(eql 1)`, `(member 1)`, `(or fixnum bignum)`, `(and (integer * 1) (integer 1 *))`, `(not (satisfies zerop))`, `(satisfies oddp)`, etc. for true results, and likewise for false results.

However, for each object, you have exactly one class:

```
 (class-of 1)
=> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS INTEGER>
```

In practice, you can't determine the whole type hierarchy.  There is the notion that anything is `t`, nothing is `nil` and there might be an hierarchy for atomic standard types.  But the reality is that there are compound types and user-defined types, so it's technically impossible to draw a full type hierarchy, as that would require to look at the result of `subtypep` for every imaginable object.

Even so, there might not exist a hierarchy between types.  Taking the *mistake* you say you found, I believe the author did not want to litter the diagram with arrows pointing to `atom` for every type other than `cons`.  But in fact, that would probably not be a correct representation at all, since some objects of type `list` and `sequence` are `cons` and others are `atom`, specifically, the empty list is `atom`.

However, you can determine the whole class hierarchy, even though a class may have multiple superclasses.

---

Some implementations return the `fixnum` class in the `class-of` example, an extension to the standard (`fixnum` is a type but not a class), to allow CLOS method specialization on `fixnum` and/or to allow optimization tricks.

From a few implementations I tried, only CLISP returned the `integer` class.

Comment: If "Types categorize objects, while classes tag objects", then does it make any sense to define a class which is a union of two other (super) classes--something akin to `(deftype symnum () '(or symbol number))`?

Comment: When you create a subclass, it inherits traits of the superclass, and this class's superclass, and so on.  With multiple superclasses, a class inherits traits from **all** of them in order, more akin to `(and super1 super2)`.  Possibly, it introduces its own traits and/or overrides some of the inherited traits.  For instance, specialized methods are traits of a class, and so are slots of standard objects.

Comment: With types, there's no intrinsic meaning about one type being a subset or a superset of other types, the meaning is given by its use and/or documentation.  For instance, you could create a type for each designator (e.g. `(deftype function-designator () '(or symbol function))`) and use it for `check-type` and/or type declarations in operations that take function designators.  An optimizing compiler could generate better code if it trusts the assertion, and even branch for when the designator is a symbol and when it is a function, and unroll the code in each branch.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Then is there any way to effectively specialize in a method something like `(defmethod x-designator (object (or symbol function ...)))` that combines specializers?

Comment: With standard methods, no.  But you may define a generic function metaclass and a method metaclass, and specialize `compute-discriminating-function`, or `compute-applicable-methods` and `compute-applicable-methods-using-classes`; you'd specify these classes on `defgeneric` and you'd have to define your own `defmethod` to parse custom specializers (or use `ensure-generic-function` and `add-method` directly).  But this is a whole topic in itself.  Start with [CLOS discriminating functions and user-defined specializers](http://www.european-lisp-workshop.org/archives/07.rhodes.pdf).