# What is the purpose of the type system in light of CLOS (Common Lisp)?

Tags: oop, lisp, common-lisp, clos

It is my understanding that the memory layout of a Common Lisp object (bitwise tagging is defined by CLOS (classes).

I understand that every class has a corresponding type, but not every type has a corresponding class, because types can be compound (lists). I think that types are like logical constraints, as opposed to classes that are concrete "types" with a tagging scheme.

If this is correct, does the type system serve any other purpose other than being a logical constraint (such as specifying that an integer must be within a certain range, or that an array contains a particular type)?

If this is not correct, what purpose does the type system actually serve in light of CLOS? Thanks.

Comment: Numbers, arrays, characters, ... are not instances of a CLOS class. Not every class is a CLOS class.

Comment: @RainerJoswig They are instances of "built-in" classes are they not? There are 3 categories of classes that are stated in CLtL2 - built-in (non-extensible), struct, and standard (the usual CLOS class - extensible, etc.)

Comment: Sure but that does not mean much. The most important purpose of this is that one can use them as parameter specializers for methods. But one can't subclass them, instances are not made by make-instance, they have no slots, ...

Comment: I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561130) a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42540781).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to get away from the implementation of things, and instead concentrate on how the language thinks about them.  Clearly the implementation needs to have enough information to know what sort of thing a given object is, and it's going to do that with some kind of 'tag' (which may or may not be some extra bits attached to the object -- some of it might be the leading bits of the address for instance).  Below I've called this the 'representational type'.  But you really have almost no access to that implementation detail from the language.  It's tempting to think that, `type-of` tells you something which maps 1-1 onto the representational type, but that's not true: `(type-of (cons 1 2)` is permitted to return `(cons integer integer)` for instance, and I think it is probably allowed to return `(cons integer number)` or `(cons (integer 1 1) (integer 2 2))`.  It's unlikely that there are distinct representational types for all of these: indeed there *can't* be since `(type-of 1)` can return `(integer m n)` for an infinite number of values of `m` & `n`.

So here's a take on how the language thinks about things, and the differences between classes and types, in CL.

Both the type system and the class system consist of a *bounded lattice* of types / classes.  Being a *lattice* means that for any pair of objects there is a unique supremum (so, for types, a unique type of which both types are subtypes, and which has no subtypes for which that is true) and infimum (the reverse).  Being *bounded* means there is a top & a bottom type / class.

### Classes

- Classes are first-class objects (you can store a class in a variable for instance).
- All objects (including classes) belong to a class, and there is a well-defined operator to find the immediate class to which any object belongs.
- There are a finite number of classes.
- The class of an object corresponds fairly closely to its representational type, but not completely (there may be specialized array types which do not have corresponding classes for instance).
- Classes can serve as types: `(type-of 1 (class-of 1))` works, as does `(subtypep (class-of 1) '(integer 0 1))` (the answers being `t` and `nil, t` respectively).

### Types

Types are ways to denote collections of objects with common properties, but they are not themselves objects: they are, if anything, just names for collections of things -- the language specification calls these 'type specifiers'.  In particular *there are an infinite number of types*: think of the type `(integer m n)` for instance.  A small number of this infinitude of types correspond to representational types -- the actual information that tells the system what sort of thing something is -- but obviously most of them do not.  There may be representational types which do not have corresponding types.

Types in practice serve three purposes I think.

- Type information can tell the system about what representational types to use which can help it check that things are the right representational type and optimise things.
- Type information can let the system make inferences which can help things significantly.
- Type information can let programmers talk about what sort of things they are dealing with, even when that information is not helpful to the system.  The system can treat such declarations as assertions about types which can make programs safer & easier to debug. This is an important reason for types: even if the system does not check them, it is useful for the person reading your code to know that it expects, say, an integer in [0, 30], ie an `(integer 0 30)`.  Indeed, even if the system does not automatically check declarations you can force checks with, say `(check-type x '(integer 0 30) ...)`.

The second case is interesting.  Let's say I have something which I have told the system is of type `(double-float 0.0d0)`.  This is very unlikely to be more useful in terms of representational type than `double-float` would be.  But if I take the square root of this thing then knowing this type might be very useful indeed: the system can know that the result is a `double-float`, rather than a `(complex double-float)`, and those types are extremely unlikely to be representationally the same.  So the system can use my type declaration to make inferences in this way (and these inferences can cascade through the program).  Note that *classes can't do this* (at least CL's classes can't), and neither can the representational type of an object: you need more information than that.

So yes, types serve a number of very useful purposes which aren't satisfied by classes.

Answer (score 4):

An object has only one class at a time, whereas it can satisfy multiple types.
The type system is a lattice, where you can compute a least-upper-bound and greatest lower bound of two types (using resp. `or`, `and`), and which admits a top type (T) and a bottom type (the NIL type, which is not the same as the  NULL type).

An implementation of Common Lisp must be able to determine if a value belongs to a type, and that starts with atomic type specifiers, like `character` or `integer`, and grows with compound type specifiers (which can be defined by the user).

But whether this is done using tags or by static analysis is left to the implementation; in practice, CL is such that there are cases where you cannot statically determine the type of an object precisely (other than T), simply because an object can be redefined at a later point: you cannot assume its type is fixed (say: a function; that's why inlining or global declarations may help with type inference).

But if you have a scope in which a type can be guaranteed to be invariant, the the compiler is free to use unboxed data types to store values. Then you don't have tagged data. That is the case for local declaration of types for variables, but also for specialized arrays: once an array is built, its element type does not change over time and in some cases knowing that an array contains only `(integer 0 15)` elements can be used to pack data more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

1. CLOS was added to CL fairly late in the game (and it was not the only object system designed for CL)
2. Even with CLOS, the type system can be used by the compiler for optimizations and by user to reason about their code.

Answer (score 1):

A type *is* a set of values.

A type specifier is some way to succinctly represent a type.

Implementations may do all kinds of markings and registering in order to help them sort out the types of things, but that is not inherent to the concept of types.

A class is an object describing a set of other objects.  Since having a succinct name for such a set (type) is quite useful, Common Lisp registers the class name as a type specifier for the corresponding set of objects.  That is the whole relation of types to classes.

Answer (score 0):

The type system defines different objects that do different things. The CLOS system is more so used for methods that define special behaviors for types in a more logical way for some programmers. Coming from Java, the CLOS System was more logical and systematic for me, so it has a role for some programmers. I like to think of the CLOS system as a class in Java such as the Integer class, and the type system similar to primitives in Java. The CLOS system simply helps you extend your objects with methods in a more systematic way than creating a structure imho.

Comment: you are mixing up a lot of different things: an object system with independent classes methods, a language to declare types, CLOS methods, Java primitives, ...